# How do you solve Vehicle Routing Problem using HERE Maps API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, here-api

I have seen **FindSequence** and **FindPicukups** API, but neither of these works for multiple vehicles, is there a way to use **Matrix** in combination with these API's to solve this ? Or any other way, using mostly HERE? I feel like the tools are the but can't seem to find the answer

Answer (score 0):

Our Fleet Telematics Waypoints Sequence APIs (FindSequence, FindPickups) currently supports only one start point and multiple destinations (1xN). We however provide a Matrix Routing API that supports multiple starts and multiple destinations (MxN) that gives summaries of route matrices. Please have a look:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/matrix-usage-guidelines.html